NN with user as a teacher
I have similar question to the following one.
Could an AI be built to learn based of interaction with a human?
What category of NN is the situation when the network learns from users feedback? The NN digests data and pass through. Than gives answer and a teacher review it by giving a score: 0.0 - failed, 1.0 - valid (or similar).
I cannot imagine, how the user's answer should be entered to the network to train it.

you are referring to RLHF
